# Testing an Icon react native component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am checking the Jest report and I have a bunch of Icons that show as not tested in this report. How can I properly test the rendering of the Icon inside of this ArrowDownIcon component using Jest? Can't find anything related in the docs, only testing buttons that have some text.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Icon} from '@ui-kitten/components';

const ArrowDownIcon = (
  props: any = {},
  styles: any = {},
  fill: string = '#000',
) => <Icon style={styles} fill={fill} name="arrow-down" {...props} />;

export default ArrowDownIcon;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is just to use `snapshot` for trivial components.

> A typical snapshot test case renders a UI component, takes a snapshot, then compares it to a reference snapshot file stored alongside the test.

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ArrowDownIcon from '<path>';

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<ArrowDownIcon />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

See [Snapshot Testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing) for details.